# Why do I have to call app.default.listen() in Express instead of app.listen()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, httpserver

I am importing my Express app into a start script, which just listens on port 5000 locally.

I configured the Express app as follows:

```
import express from 'express'
import bodyParser from 'body-parser'
import cors from 'cors'
import helmet from 'helmet'
import router from '../../routes'

const restServer = express()

const middleWare = [
  helmet(),
  bodyParser.json(),
  bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }),
  cors({
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    allowedHeaders: 'Content-Type, Authorization',
    methods: ['GET, POST, PUT, DELETE', 'OPTIONS']
  })
]

restServer.use(...middleWare)

if (process.env.DEBUG === 'TRUE') {
  const logger = require('morgan')
  restServer.use(logger('dev'))
}

restServer.use('/api', router)

export default restServer
```

When I import this file into my start script, I tried to run

`app.listen(5000, (err) => {
  if (err) throw new Error()
  console.log('successfully connected to port', PORT)
})`

but it throws a TypeError: app.listen is not a function

It works when I call `app.default.listen(5000)`

I'm using Express 4.16.4

Comment: What is app in your case ? can you please show the respected code also ?

Comment: app is just this file imported, sorry if that wasn't clear